# Android layout with two edittexts?

Tags: android

I would like to create a layout for an android application where I have two edittexts at the same height. If I put those edittexts one after the other in the xml code I will have the second below the first, even changing the gravity. I would like to put a textview on each edittext, and it they should be at the same height as well.
It should look like this fabulous representation. Thanks!!!!!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html), It should look like the following pseudocode

```
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <EditText />
    <EditText />
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```